# printing character at even and odd position of a multiple strings

Tags: c

I am trying to print characters of a given string at even and odd positions of using **c** program. My program is working fine if there is only one string but it not working for a sentence containing more than one string.The following code only prints the second string entered, but it does not printing the characters at even and odd positions as it was doing for the very first string.

```
int main() 
{
char string[10], even[10], odd[10], i, j, k,count;

i = j = k = count = 0;

    do
    {
    printf("Enter your input string:");
    fgets(string, 10, stdin);
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';

    /* printing the input string */
    printf("Given Input string:%s\n", string);

        while (string[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
            odd[j++] = string[i];
            }
            else {
            even[k++] = string[i];
            }
        i++;
        }
    /*  terminating even and odd string with NULL */
    odd[j] = even[k] = '\0';

    /* print the characters at odd position and even positions */
    printf(" %s %s", odd,even);

    odd[0]=even[0]='\0';
    count++;
    }while(count<2);
return 0;
}
```

At execution when I entered the first string as "united", it printed out "uie" for the odd position and "ntd" for the even position. Then I am prompted to enter the second string which I entered as "states" but nothing printed out except the string entered and the program exits. It did not output as it did for the first string. 
Please help me to point out my mistake so that my code should work correctly for any number of strings rather than only for first string i.e it should output the characters at even and odd positions for all of the strings entered by the user.

Comment: You forgot to reset the local variables.

Comment: `i`, `j`, and `k` are not being reset to 0.

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake now. I fixed and it is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Format/indent your code correctly.

Comment: `string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';` This is what some people call **cargo cult programming**. Can you explain in minute details what this line does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are restricting yourself to an archaic version of C syntax that required all local variables to be declared at the top of a block, ahead of any executable statements.

Since your code is not using variables other than `count` outside the `do`/`while` loop, you should move their declarations inside the loop. This will ensure that the variables have appropriate initial values at the beginning of each iteration.

Here are a few additional points to keep in mind:

- Your code will result in undefined behavior if an end-user terminates the input stream (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on UNIX) without entering any characters
- Your code will drop the last character when end-user terminates input stream after entering less than ten characters
- `odd[0]=even[0]='\0'` is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

using namespace std;

```
struct str
{
    char s[10000];
};

int main() {

    int T;
    cin >> T;
    fflush(stdin);
    str s1[10];
    while (T--) {
        cin >> s1[T].s;
        fflush(stdin);

        int j = 0;
        while (j < strlen(s1[T].s)) {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
                cout << s1[T].s[j];
            ++j;
        }
        cout << " ";
        int k = 0;
        while (k < strlen(s1[T].s)) {
            if (k % 2 == 1)
                cout << s1[T].s[k];
            ++k;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```